# WPF: AutoComplete TextBox, ...again

Tags: wpf, textbox, autocomplete

[This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950770/autocomplete-textbox-in-wpf) asks about an autocomplete textbox in WPF.  Several people have built these, and one of the answers given there suggests [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/autocomplete-textbox.aspx).

But I've not found any WPF Autocomplete Textbox that compares with the WinForms autocomplete textbox.  The codeproject sample works, sort of, ...

[image]

...but

- it isn't structured as a re-usable control or DLL.  It's code I need to embed in every app.
- It works only with directories.  it doesn't have properties for setting whether the autocomplete source is filesystem directories only, or filesystem files, or ....etc.  I could write code to do this, of course, but...I'd rather use someone else's code already written.
- it doesn't have properties to set the popup size, etc.
- there's a popup listbox that presents the posible completions. When navigating through that list, the textbox doesn't change.  Typing a character while focused in the listbox doesn't cause the textbox to get updated.
- navigating focus away from the listbox doesn't make the popup listbox disappear. This is confusing.

So, my question:

*Does anyone have a FREE WPF AutoComplete textbox ***that works***, and provides a quality UI experience?*

---

**ANSWER**

Here's how I did it:

.0. get the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535)

.1. run the MSI for the WPF Toolkit

.2. Within Visual Studio, Drag/drop from the toolbox - specifically the Data Visualization group - into the UI Designer.  It looks like this in the VS toolbox:

[image]

If you don't want to use the designer, hand-craft the xaml.  It looks like this:

---

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox
   ToolTip="Enter the path of an assembly."
   x:Name="tbAssembly" Height="27" Width="102"
   Populating="tbAssembly_Populating" />
```

...where the toolkit namespace is mapped this way:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
```

---

.3. Provide the code for the `Populating` event.  Here's what I used:

---

```
private void tbAssembly_Populating(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.PopulatingEventArgs e)
{
    string text = tbAssembly.Text;
    string dirname = Path.GetDirectoryName(text);

    if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(dirname)))
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirname, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirname, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        var candidates = new List<string>();

        Array.ForEach(new String[][] { files, dirs }, (x) =>
            Array.ForEach(x, (y) =>
                      {
                          if (y.StartsWith(dirname, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                              candidates.Add(y);
                      }));

        tbAssembly.ItemsSource = candidates;
        tbAssembly.PopulateComplete();
    }
}
```

---

It works, just the way you'd expect.  It feels professional. There are none of the anomalies that the codeproject control exhibits. This is what it looks like:

[image]

---

[Thanks to Matt for the pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338690/wpf-autocomplete-textbox-again/2338707#2338707) to the WPF toolkit.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The newest drop of the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) includes an AutoCompleteBox. It's a free set of controls from Microsoft, some of which will be included in .NET 4.

[Jeff Wilcox - Introducing the AutoCompleteBox](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/10/introducing-autocompletebox/)

Comment: Sounds intriguing, Matt.  Is there a guide or example on using the AutoCompleteBox?  I found the DLL that contains it.  What xmlns do I use in XAML?  How do I actually use it?

Comment: Note that the blog post link I just added talks about Silverlight, but AutoCompleteBox is for WPF too.

Comment: WPF Toolkit on CodePlex is dead, but there're several forks on GitHub, if anyone needs that: [jogibear9988/wpftoolkit](https://github.com/jogibear9988/wpftoolkit), [WPFToolkit.DataVisualization](https://github.com/davidalpert/WPFToolkit.DataVisualization), [theonlylawislove/WPFToolkit](https://github.com/theonlylawislove/WPFToolkit), [jrwren/wpftoolkit](https://github.com/jrwren/wpftoolkit).

Comment: Another blog post on how to use it: http://www.broculos.net/2014/04/wpf-autocompletebox-autocomplete-text.html#.VG8UKvndVAU

Answer (score 17):

Here's how I did it:

.1. run the MSI for the WPF Toolkit

.2. Within Visual Studio, Drag/drop from the toolbox - specifically the Data Visualization group - into the UI Designer.  It looks like this in the VS toolbox:

[image]

Or, hand-craft the xaml.  It looks like this:

---

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox
   ToolTip="Enter the path of an assembly."
   x:Name="tbAssembly" Height="27" Width="102"
   Populating="tbAssembly_Populating" />
```

...where the toolkit namespace is mapped this way:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
```

---

.3. Provide the code for the `Populating` event.  Here's what I used:

---

```
private void tbAssembly_Populating(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.PopulatingEventArgs e)
{
    string text = tbAssembly.Text;
    string dirname = Path.GetDirectoryName(text);

    if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(dirname)))
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirname, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirname, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        var candidates = new List<string>();

        Array.ForEach(new String[][] { files, dirs }, (x) =>
            Array.ForEach(x, (y) =>
                      {
                          if (y.StartsWith(dirname, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                              candidates.Add(y);
                      }));

        tbAssembly.ItemsSource = candidates;
        tbAssembly.PopulateComplete();
    }
}
```

---

Thanks to Matt for the pointer to the WPF toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Intellibox in my in-house project. http://intellibox.codeplex.com/

I find it's use of the Provider pattern for searching very intuitive.

Rake's answer provides an example of how to use it, and as he points out, it has seen some development late last year (although this is well after I last used it).

Comment: http://intellibox.codeplex.com/ does seem to updated as recently as Oct 1, 2013 and contains the single control. (Thanks, Rake)

Comment: Yes I haven't worked on that for a while, nice to know it has seen some attention since then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Mindscape also provides a [3 free controls](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/wpfelements/free-controls) including a WPF Autocomplete Textbox

http://intellibox.codeplex.com/ does seem to updated as recently as Oct 1, 2013 and contains the single control. I would have added as comment on Troy's answer, but don't have enough rep. I nearly ignored it because of that comment.

Example usage from documentation:

```
    <auto:Intellibox ResultsHeight="80"
                     ExplicitlyIncludeColumns="True"
                     Name="lightspeedBox"
                     DisplayedValueBinding="{Binding Product_Name}"
                     SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Product_Id}"
                     DataProvider="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                     AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=LinqToEntitiesProvider}"
                     Height="26"
                     Margin="12,26,12,0"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <auto:Intellibox.Columns>
            <auto:IntelliboxColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Product_Name}"
                                   Width="150"
                                   Header="Product Name" />
            <auto:IntelliboxColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Unit_Price}"
                                   Width="75"
                                   Header="Unit Price" />
            <auto:IntelliboxColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Suppliers.Company_Name}"
                                   Width="125"
                                   Header="Supplier" />
        </auto:Intellibox.Columns>
    </auto:Intellibox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try WPF Auto Complete TextBox at CodePlex here: https://wpfautocomplete.codeplex.com/

Comment: I see this is your project, and it looks good, but you should do more than just add a link here. Add some sample code, instructions, show why it is a possible solution for the OP. StackOverflow is a Q&A wiki essentially, so users expect to see enough detail in the answer to see that that solution will work for them without being taken away from this site. By all means direct people to the codeplex site for further info.

Comment: I've spent my morning vetting autocomplete textboxes I found in different places on the net. This one is by far the best, and is the one I'll be using in my project.