# Best way to perform an ajax auto complete search box in WPF?

Tags: wpf, autocomplete

I have been trying to do this with the AutoCompleteBox tool in the WPF Tool Kit. What event would best be used if I wanted to display information from a database based on what the user enters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try handling the Populating event as per the following:

[WPF: AutoComplete TextBox, ...again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338690/wpf-autocomplete-textbox-again)

Comment: thanks! i had been referring to that article. However, when I try to access my AutoComplete box anywhere but the MainWindow function I get a "The name 'codebox' does not exist in the current context". I tried just setting it with codebox.ItemsSource = codesList; codebox.PopulateComplete();