# AutoComplete functionality for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, binding, autosuggest

I have 20 controls on my WPF page which are binded to a static resource "InsertClass". Out of those 20, one is a buyer texbox, on which user can enter the name of buyer. Now, what i require is that when a user starts entering, he should get a suggestion list via popup or dropdown list so that he can select it incase the buyer already exist. If there isn't any buyer matching, a "new buyer" event or link should popup.

I have uploaded the three files associated with this problem on my skydrive. Download the Desktop.arc folder [HERE](http://cid-d4801666b0996f88.office.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public)

Let me know what will you do when this code is given to you and are asked to add the auto-complete functionality to buyerText control in NewRecord.xaml

Comment: You can use the AutoCompleteTextbox control from [WPF Toolkit - February 2010 Release](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) Check these links for more info https://stackoverflow.com/q/2338690/217880 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/537/