# AutoCompleteBox - WPF Toolkit

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to use the AutoCompleteBox in my WPF  application but i cannot find it in visual studio. I have VS 2010 ultimate. I just downloaded and installed WPFToolkit.msi and ran it. When i open VS i cannot find the control. Where can i find it? Do i have to reference it somehow? I also have the .dll but i dont know if i need to put that somewhere? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AutoComplete textbox is a componenet which is in the [Preview Quality Band](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quality%20Bands) in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) .So it is not available is visualstudio 2010.You need to download and install the Feb 2010 release of the WpfToolkit and follow the instructions from the below SO post

[WPF: AutoComplete TextBox, ...again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2338690/217880)