# Bind Combobox with huge data in WPF

Tags: wpf, performance, combobox, large-data

I am trying to bind combobox with custom object list. My object list have around 15K record and combobox takes long time to show the data after clicking on combobox.

Below are the code:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Name="comboBox1" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="EmpName" SelectedValue="EmpID" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
```

code behind:

```
List<EmployeeBE> allEmployee = new List<EmployeeBE>();
allEmployee = EmployeeBO.GetEmployeeAll();
 comboBox1.ItemsSource = allEmployee;
```

allEmployee have around 15K record.
Can any one Suggest how can I improve my combobox performance?

Comment: Consider not using a ComboBox.. A ComboBox with 15k records is pretty brutal to navigate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a `VirtualizingStackPanel` as described here - http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/12/15/wpf-using-a-virtualizingstackpanel-to-improve-combobox-performance.aspx

As others have said, you really want to re-imagine your UI, as a ComboBox isn't appropriate for 15k records.

Answer (score 5):

That's bad UI design: No user will read through 15K records.

You can improve the performance by allowing the user to enter some filter criteria before showing the results, for example, by using an [AutoCompleteBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338690/wpf-autocomplete-textbox-again) instead of a ComboBox.

Comment: Agreed, `AutoCompleteBox` or even an appropriate `ListBox` with text search enabled is definitely the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `VirtualizingStackPanel` as `ItemsPanel` for the `ComboBox`.

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxItemsPanelTemplate"> 
   <VirtualizingStackPanel/> 
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<ComboBox ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsTemplate}"/>
```