# Paging in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, paging

I am using ItemTemplate to customize how data be shown in ComboBox. But my record count is very big. So that it takes a long time to render the items. Is there anyway to add paging to ComboBox in WPF?

I searched the internet and found some solutions. for example: http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/12/15/wpf-using-a-virtualizingstackpanel-to-improve-combobox-performance.aspx

But unfortunately because I render the items using a grid, I still have this problem!!!.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind Combobox with huge data in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610601/bind-combobox-with-huge-data-in-wpf)

Comment: I saw that post and it's solution. But it doesn't answer for my problem. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the properties

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"     
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

?

```
<ComboBox VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"     
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
```

Comment: Yes. I have tried both. I cannot use `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` for some rendering reasons. But I'm using `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"`