# Manipulate a list within textbox textchange event in C# desktop application

Tags: c#

I have a product list with 1000 item
Now I want to search an item by textbox textchange event
Let i want an item that contain "Pleate" as first or middle or last part of Item
If i write "Pleate" in text box then manipulate a list/ Suggestion list which are contain with 
"Pleate"

Like following Image :

[image]

then i select a item from list as well as list will be vanish

Comment: You want to implement an autocomplete control. Try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44920/A-Reusable-WPF-Autocomplete-TextBox

Comment: Andrey Gordeev Is it possible without WPF?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought you use WPF. Here is one for WinForms: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16285/Auto-Complete-ComboBox

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: AutoComplete TextBox, ...again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338690/wpf-autocomplete-textbox-again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var data = new[] { "Plate", "Table", "Cap" }; //Place your 'product list' into the IEnumerable<string> data
listBox.DataSource = data.Where(item => item.Contains(textBox.Text));
```