# WPF Toolkit Autocomplete Trouble

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, wpftoolkit

I installed the WPF Toolkit using the following NuGet command.

PM> Install-Package WPFToolkit

and then I followed the code in this link to create an autocomplete control without using the designer drag and drop:

[WPF: AutoComplete TextBox, ...again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338690/wpf-autocomplete-textbox-again/2338707#2338707)

When I ran it, I'm getting this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If someone could tell me what I'm missing, that would be very helpful.

Comment: have you included this assembly in your project REFERENCE..?

Comment: Check the DLL is trusted.   If it comes from a ZIP then trust the zip before install.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's trusted but let me check it.

Comment: Btw I'm using visual studio 2010. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be caused by windows security restictions, Try to run VS2010 as Administrator, Uninstall WPF Toolkit using nuget and then reinstall it.

Comment: oooh this sounds promising. I'll give it a try tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You need to include that assembly in the project references:

Right click "References", then "Add reference".

Comment: the reference gets added when the NuGet package is installed