# AJAX Style "Suggestions" in WPF

Tags: c#, ajax, wpf

I have a datagrid (having all columns as *DataGridTextColumn*) showing data of a child table. Now there are some columns which are bringing a Foreign Key value from Parent Table.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DMS.Presentation.CustomerWorkSpaceView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DMS.Presentation"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                
                <DataGrid Name="datagridCustomers" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Loaded="datagridCustomers_Loaded" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact No" Binding="{Binding Path=ContactNo}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company ID" Binding="{Binding Path=CompanyID}"></DataGridTextColumn>                       
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </HeaderedContentControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
</Grid>
```

***What I want to Do***

If user edits the cell of a Foreign Key column (say Company ID), it should start suggesting it the possible values (just like Twitter starts suggesting the names using AJAX the moment we type @ or # - refer to screenshot).

[image: Twitter Suggestions]

*By Possible Values I mean*

Simply the rows of COMPANY table. I want to get the result of this query as possible values:

```
SELECT * FROM COMPANY
WHERE ID LIKE '%@IDEnteredValue%'
```

(where IDEnteredValue means value entered in cell of ID in our grid)

I ONLY need its Front-end Implementation

Comment: So you are saying you already have the result of the query working, you just don't know how to make the text box use those values like an auto complete filter?

Comment: Yes Zack. Exactly! I want those values to be hovered there just like they do in Twitter, etc as I have shown in modified answer

Comment: Only thing I can find is the WPF Toolkit which includes an AutoCompleteBox, http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535 and the article introducing it http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/10/introducing-autocompletebox/ from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2338707/1804496 The article is talking about Silverlight, so maybe that is not the right one anyway..

Comment: Can't we make a custom control and show there as "ToolTip/Suggestions"?

Comment: There is this https://wpfautocomplete.codeplex.com/ WPF AutoComplete project that was updated on March 10th that looks promising.

Comment: Thanks. But does it work for dataGrid as well?

Comment: I don't think you can just replace the DataGridTextColumn with the AutoCompleteTextBox straight up, but you could use a DataGridTemplateColumn and put an AutoCompleteTextBox in the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate like is shown here http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/