# AutoCompleteTextBox in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, textbox

I've seen a number of suggestions for `AutoComplete` in WPF on a `TextBox`. However, they are all years old by now and many are expired without working websites.

Basically, I'm going to want to bind the `TextBox` to an `ObservableCollection` with a `Model` of a  `Person`. Their `Name` will be displayed wen the user types as a suggestion, and will be displayed when the user selects said `Person`.

However I also want to be able to access the selected `Persons` ID as well. Is there a `TextBox` that is still current and can achieve what I would like it to do?

EDIT: I've attempted to use [WPF TextBox AutoComplete](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFTextBoxAutoComplete/1.0.2) like so:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ContactMadeBy, ElementName=contactsDataGrid, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" behaviors:AutoCompleteBehavior.AutoCompleteItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollection}"/>
```

but nothing happens when I type. I've looped through `EmployeeCollection` and it is definitely populated, so the issue lies with the `TextBox`. An additional problem to this is that it needs to be bound to an `IEnumerable<string>` where I can't have the `Persons` ID as well.

Comment: There is no `AutoCompleteTextBox` in wpf. You have to either use someone's or create own control. Show what you done, what doesn't work (how you want it to work) and question may become less [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2338690/1997232)/broad.

Comment: @Sinatr I've updated my answer to show what I've tried so far.