# Expression Blend 4 - AutoCompleteBox not available for WPF application

Tags: wpf, silverlight

It looks like there is an AutoComplete box in Expression Blend 4, but it looks like it doesn't let you use it on a regular WPF application.  Can this be true?  Is it only available for Silverlight applictions?  If so, is there one I can use in a WPF application written for .Net 4?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the `AutoCompleteBox` is only available in Silverlight... no idea why. However, there are plenty of auto-complete textbox implementations for WPF... See this answer for details :

[AutoComplete TextBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950770/autocomplete-textbox-in-wpf/1762647#1762647)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  At least you have confirmed that it is only available in Silverlight.  I wonder if Microsoft have plans to make it available to WPF too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems [WPF toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) has an AutoCompleteBox.

Comment: Ah, OK thanks.  It seems like I might have to use that one and therefore make my project dependent on .Net 3.5 as well as .Net 4

Comment: 3.5 is included in 4 so you're not adding any dependencies by referencing a 3.5 assembly.