# How to store data in WPF?

Tags: wpf, cookies, storing-data

I want to store data in my WPF application. For example: the user writes his name in text box in the loading of the application. I want to show him the last name that he entered the text box, after he exists my application and restarts it.

I don't want to use a database, I want to create some kind of cookie that will saved locally on the client computer.

Comment: `How to store data in WPF?` - WPF is a Presentation Framework. It has nothing to do with data. Use a database, an XML file, app.settings file, or any other data storage means, but this is in no-way related to WPF itself.

Comment: If you dont got that much data, you can story it in the application's `Settings`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Are you meaning something like this?

[AutoComplete TextBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950770/autocomplete-textbox-in-wpf)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44920/A-Reusable-WPF-Autocomplete-TextBox

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26535/WPF-Autocomplete-Textbox-Control

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/408532/Autocomplete-textbox-in-WPF

Textbox that remembers the name if typed previously?