# Logging user input and with user input besides

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, winapp

How to

1. record the user keyboard input (when they are typing)
2. shows a small interface beside the windows for words suggestion

for Windows

just like the following?

I am thinking using C#, (if java or C or C++ has an answered, I am interested also, as I am not sure which language implement this is better). Note this this is not a web application, it is a windows application.

[image]

Comment: If you are using WPF, this link might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950770/autocomplete-textbox-in-wpf

Comment: If you are using Windows SDK/MFC, catch the ON_EN_CHANGE notification.