# WPF Auto Complete Text box property

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, autocomplete, visual-studio-2015

I am very new to C# and WPF. I have been developing and application in which I need to use an auto complete text box. For that, I follow the article in this link. http://net-informations.com/q/faq/autocomplete.html

But when I code, Visual Studio gives me the error saying,

> 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for
>   'AutoCompleteSource' and no extension method 'AutoCompleteSource'....

As I think the reason might be, WPF does not contain the definition for Auto Complete textbox. Therefore As I found in a comment for the second answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950770/autocomplete-textbox-in-wpf) question, I added the WPF toolkit and added the reference to my project(as described [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535)).

But still I don't see the autocomplete text box getting appeared in my tool box and that above mentioned error getting disappeared.

Why is this and how Can I get autocomplete text box into my tool box?

Answer (score 1):

`WPF` doesn't have an in-built `AutoComplete` `TextBox`. You need to use third-party software, try something like this;

[WPF TextBox AutoComplete 1.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFTextBoxAutoComplete/)

or

[WPF AutoComplete](https://wpfautocomplete.codeplex.com/)

The article you were following uses `WinForms`, which `WPF` is the new version of.

Comment: Then irrespective of forms or WPF, I will be able to use this. right?

Comment: @vigamage the ones I linked you will only work in `WPF`. in `WinForms` You can just use the in-built `TextBox` which has `AutoComplete` already built into it.

Comment: I am going to use the NuGet one. I installed it and now trying to code the control for that. (to load data from db to datacontext). since I am new to C#(I am from Java background) I find it difficult to bind the text box and the data I have in the DB. Any examples for this online?

Comment: [Tutorial](https://github.com/Nimgoble/WPFTextBoxAutoComplete) - try this @vigamage