# Winforms ComboBox autocomplete search multiple parts of string

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

Very similar question to this one...
[Autocomplete for ComboBox in WPF anywhere in text (not just beginning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522521/autocomplete-for-combobox-in-wpf-anywhere-in-text-not-just-beginning) but my issue is for windows-forms rather than WPF.

I have a winforms databound combox working great with autocomplete list coming from the data items in the combobox.

Of course the client wants it to work "better", and that means that they want the autocomplete to work by searching and showing autocomplete options for any matching (contains()) string not just the starting string (startswith())

I know it's probably not just a property that can be set in the combobox, but can anyone point me in the right direction?