# How to enable autocomplete on combobox?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a combo box (cboBox), and I am giving it a list of items to its DataContext and ItemsSource.

I've also made the combo box editable; but I am not sure how to enable autocomplete while typing into the editable combobox.

Is there a way to enable autocomplete without using 3rd party tools? If not, what is the best alternative if a combobox MUST be used?

Comment: [Poss duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522521/autocomplete-for-combobox-in-wpf-anywhere-in-text-not-just-beginning)

Comment: Saw that, but I'm hoping for something that's already available through basic WPF. Though, the answer there is a good alternative.